# MAMP, Mac, Magento (2.4.2p1)

Tags: php, macos, magento, mamp

Trying to get a local Magento implementation on my Mac. After trying a number of approaches (Homebrew, Homebrew with valet+, etc - too many configuration issues and magento not installing correctly) with none working, I'm back to MAMP.

Got the latest MAMP on Big Sur. Set ports to 80, got composer 2.1.1, MAMP has php 7.4.12 - should all be good. But when I try to do a composer install of Magento (in the proper document root), I get a php error - no intl. This shouldn't be - I'm wondering if this is a PATH issue to the right php? It shows apache's is 7.3.24 so I know it's not using the right php, plus a php -m shows no intl. The MAMP page's php 7.4 has everything in place.

The config file path in MAMP to php (in the MAMP profile screen) is:
`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/conf`

The Mac terminal path is (echo $PATH):
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin`

Is this my issue? If not, what?

I wouldn't think this should be so hard, but then....

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

When using command line, you will probably need to specify the path to the MAMP PHP version like:
`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/bin/php`

You might also need to specify the composer path, so it might end up as:
`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/bin/php /usr/local/bin/composer install`

It will be similar for all your Magento command line tasks as you manage the site, like:
`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.12/bin/php bin/magento setup:upgrade`